# Save long values separately

Tags: android

Below code returns 4 values (91891, 31881, 7820, 181655), i want to store them in 4 separate long values so that i can compare them later.

Is that possible? Thank you for your help.

```
private long getLatest(final ForumPage page) {
    long latest = -1;
    long val1; //91891
    long val2; //31881
    long val3; //7820
    long val4; //181655

    for (final Topic t : page.getTopics()) {
        Date d;
        try {
            d = Util.parseDate(t.getTime());
        } catch (final ParseException e) {
            d = null;
        }

        if (d != null) {
            final long time = d.getTime();
            if (time > latest)
                latest = time;
        }
    }
    Log.v("COUNT: ", String.valueOf(page.getTopicCount()));
    return latest;
}
```

---

```
01-01 11:55:53.928: E/COUNT:(2871): 91891
01-01 11:55:54.548: E/COUNT:(2871): 31881
01-01 11:55:54.796: E/COUNT:(2871): 7820
01-01 11:55:56.378: E/COUNT:(2871): 181655
```

---

Edit, ForumPage Class with getTopicCount:

```
public class ForumPage implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1057995133618054945L;

private int page;
private int maxPage;
private int nextPageStart;
private int topicCount;
private String name;
private final List<Topic> topics = new ArrayList<Topic>();

public int getPage() {
    return page;
}

public void setPage(final int page) {
    this.page = page;
}

public int getMaxPage() {
    return maxPage;
}

public void setMaxPage(final int maxPage) {
    this.maxPage = maxPage;
}

public int getNextPageStart() {
    return nextPageStart;
}

public void setNextPageStart(final int nextPageStart) {
    this.nextPageStart = nextPageStart;
}

public int getTopicCount() {
    return topicCount;
}

public void setTopicCount(final int topicCount) {
    this.topicCount = topicCount;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void addTopic(final Topic topic) {
    topics.add(topic);
}

public Topic[] getTopics() {
    return topics.toArray(new Topic[topics.size()]);
}
```

}

Comment: I can't understand , What exactly you want do ? You want save the values ?

Comment: use ArrayList<Long> to solve problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a List of Integer (or ArrayList, as you like) in your class:

```
List<Integer> valuesList = new List<Integer>();
```

Then save your values like that:

```
private long getLatest(final ForumPage page) {
    long latest = -1;    
    for (final Topic t : page.getTopics()) {
        Date d;
        try {
            d = Util.parseDate(t.getTime());
        } catch (final ParseException e) {
            d = null;
        }

        if (d != null) {
            final long time = d.getTime();
            if (time > latest)
                latest = time;
        }
    }
    Log.v("COUNT: ", String.valueOf(page.getTopicCount()));
    valuesList.add(page.getTopicCount());

    return latest;
}
```

You'll find all your values in `valuesList`

Edit here is the getTopics and getLatest function:

```
public Topic[] getTopics() { //4 Topics
    return topics.toArray(new Topic[topics.size()]);
}

public long getLatest(final String suffix) {
    final String latest = get(KEY_LATEST + suffix);
    if (latest != null) {
        try {
            return Long.parseLong(latest);
        } catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
            //
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: thx but doesn`t work, i`ll get following error for the code valuesList.add(String.valueOf(page.getTopicCount())); The method add(Long) in the type ArrayList<Long> is not applicable for the arguments (String), change to addAll();

Comment: Works now, List should be Integer not Long: List<Integer> valuesList = new List<Integer>();
Accepted answer for leading the right way, thx Rami.

Comment: Thanks, i haven't tested my code, you are right i'll update it.

Comment: Still 1 problem Rami, the values are not stored 'seperatly'.
For instance if id do:
int value = valuesList.get(0);
     System.out.println("Element: " + value);
All 4 values are displayes, it should be only 91891.
Like:
valuesList.get(0); //91891
valuesList.get(1); //31881
valuesList.get(2); //7820
valuesList.get(3); //181655

Comment: It's strange. Can you post your full class code? exactly the code where you create the list for the first time, and from where you call getLatest() method.

Comment: i edited your answer with the code involved.
I think i need to access the Topic[] value but i don`t know how

Comment: Update your question code not my answer, and i want to see the full code. I don't see *getTopicCount()* method, maybe it returns a wrong value. For your question: Topic[] is an array(as i see in your code) so try to get values with t.[0]; t.[1]; ..... inside the loop (the *for(...)*)

Comment: i edited my code and inserted the whole ForumPage class including getTopicCount() funtion.

Comment: Why you have 2 *getLatest()* methods (getLatest(String) and getLatest(ForumPage))?. I want the see the piece of code from where you call *getLatest(ForumPage)*